# How add TreeNode to TreeNodeCollection with more than name and text in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes, treenode, treenodecollection

I want to add to my treeview some nodes with childs, but have a problem how to add nodes with for example ToolTipText. I want do it with TreeNodeCollection.
It is possible or how could I change my code?
Here is my code where all nodes are root nodes.

```
protected void CreateTreeView(TreeNodeCollection parentNode, int parentID, DataTable mytab)
        {
        foreach (DataRow dta in mytab.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(dta["parent_id"]) == parentID)
            {
                String key = dta["id"].ToString();
                String text = dta["host_ip"].ToString();
                TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
                tn.Name = dta["id"].ToString();
                tn.Text = dta["host_ip"].ToString();
                tn.ToolTipText = dta["description"].ToString();
                parentNode.Add(tn);

                TreeNodeCollection newParentNode = parentNode;
                CreateTreeView(newParentNode, Convert.ToInt32(dta["id"]), mytab);
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling code:

```
CreateTreeView(treeView1.Nodes, 0, dt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone had with this problem here is an example:

```
void add_tooltiptext(DataTable mytab)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (DataRow nodes in mytab.Rows)
            {
                TreeNode[] found = treeView1.Nodes.Find(nodes["id"].ToString(), true);
                for (int i = 0; i < found.Length; i++)
                {
                    treeView1.SelectedNode = found[i];

                    treeView1.SelectedNode.ToolTipText = nodes["description"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```